# mysqldump not working at all :(

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code :

```
function export() 
{
    $exp = system("mysqldump -uguku -pjustbe repadmin > back-up.sql");
    if($exp) {echo 'ok';}
    else { echo 'err';}
}
```

But it doesn't work, all it does, is to create the "back-up.sql" file, but it's blank.
And I get the "err" message.

Comment: first you should see if running: mysqldump -uroot -p repadmin on the console works.  the mysql_connect, mysql_select_db stuff your doing is irrelevant to the system() call.  2 different things.

Comment: it works just fine from the console, it doesn't from the php script
:(, this is the line that worked on the console: 
"mysqldump -uguku -pjustbe repadmin > back-up.sql" and in the "bin" folder a file with this name is created and it works. When i run the script on the PHP page, the "back-up.sql" file is created but no code inside it.

Comment: `-p` is going to prompt for a password unless you give it a value.  You're not currently giving it a value in the code you have above.

Comment: in addition to all the comments and suggestions here, you should also use -r back-up.sql instead of > back-up.sql.  since your executing it in php as 1 command, you don't have the shell's redirection stuff.

Comment: i changed the code, -pjustbe, it still doesn't work.

Comment: @spotman If there is an empty file, then the redirection is working just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the full path to mysqldump...

`$exp = system("/full/path/mysqldump -uroot -p repadmin > back-up.sql");`

`which mysqldump` will tell you what the path should be.

Comment: Anyway i type the full path, simple or with brackets ... in PHP it doesn't work, in console yes, perfectly, but on the script, no :(

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a command that's not running properly. Best thing to do is to capture stderr (where error messages go) and see what the output is. Another thing to note is that environment variables will be different - such as the PATH (refered to by @Joshua_Martell above).

Use this command to capture stderr and see what error messages are being produced:

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump -uguku -pjustbe repadmin > back-up.sql 2> mysqldump.err
```

This also uses a full path to `mysqldump` (use the right path). You also probably should add a path to `back-up.sql` and, in this case, to `mysqldump.err` - don't assume that PHP will run in the directory you want as it *could* change.